# What (type of) partition is needed to install Fedora alongside Windows

Tags: fedora, partition, windows, dual-boot

I've been trying to install Fedora on my laptop since ... last night.
I tried the instructions from [this page](http://www.tecmint.com/install-fedora-21-dual-boot-with-windows-8/).

But I got an error saying

> local variable 'e' was referenced before... ( my memory fades)

I think it was because I already had at least 3 primary partitions( I didn't really notice that then nor I ever cared to look at before).

After fiddling with Windows Disk Management (using mmc), I managed to have a 300GB big **unallocated** space with 3 other primary partitions.
This time I was able to create either swap or /boot. But then again I hit the
"local variable 'e' was referenced..." error. Again, I think it was because of the number of primary partitions.

So I have now only 1 primary partition and 1 extended partition which includes, a system recovery logical partition, C: where Windows is and a green "free space".
See the photo here.[image]

Now when I try to install Fedora, I get
[image]

But in a document ( I think it was the official reference but I can't find the exact location anymore ), it said that I need **unallocated** partition to be able to install Fedora. (I was reading somewhere around [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/20/html/Installation_Guide/index.html)

So I'm confused and banging my head against this wall.

How do I install Fedora on my machine alongside Windows 10 ?
Is the second photo an actual bug that has not been addressed ?

See also [Yes, Fedora supports installing into logical partitions inside an extended partition.](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/72347/does-fedora-support-installation-to-logical-partitions/#post-id-72352)  from Ask Fedora

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug of the Anaconda installer (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1259745).
Since the bug is closed you probably should download a new ISO and retry the installation.

Answer (score 0):

You may could try one of the following things:

1. You create one ext4 and one linux-swap partition in a live-enviroment (e.g. [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/download.php)).
2. You try to install another distribution (e.g. Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of space in the extended partition.  My recommendation would be to choose ext3 or ext4 partition in the extended partition while installing the grub to it's default location in the mbr.  This will give you a grub that recognizes windows and at the same time will also load fedora on the allocated space on the extended partition.